# how many threads/connections does Django use to make DML queries?

Tags: django

How many connections or db backends connections/threads does django use to make DML query?
If there are two requests from users to change data in DB in same time(+- 0.3 sec), will django make them parallel or in series? or it depends on settings? In case that there is one DB and one server.

Answer (score 0):

[Transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/). No, really, [transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/).